# CS50 credit doesn't run for some numbers

Tags: c, cs50

My code seems to work on some credit card numbers but for others it doesn't even run. I've tried to use long long for the credit card number but it didn't worked. I've spent like 2 hours trying to solve this issue but I can't figure it out. All help is welcomed :)

```
int main(void)
{
    // Get credit card number
    long num = get_cc_number();

    // Check if the credit card number is valid
    valid = check_sum(num);

    // Check the length of the credit card number
    length = check_length(num);

    // Get the first two digits of the credit card number and first number of VISA
    digits = get_first_digits(num);
    digit_visa = digits / 10;

    // Check if the card is American Express, Mastercard, Visa or Invalid
    if (valid == 1)
    {
        if (length == 16)
        {
            if (digits <= 55 && digits >= 51)
            {
                printf("MASTERCARD\n");
            }
            else if (digit_visa == 4)
            {
                printf("VISA\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("INVALID\n");
            }
        }
        else if (length == 15)
        {
            if (digits == 34 || digits == 37)
            {
                printf("AMEX\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("INVALID\n");
            }
        }
        else if (length == 13)
        {
            if (digit_visa == 4)
            {
                printf("VISA\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("INVALID\n");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }
}

long get_cc_number(void)
{
    long cc_number;
    cc_number = get_long("Credit Card Number: ");
    return cc_number;
}

int check_sum(int num)
{
    int num1 = num;
    while (num1 >= 10)
    {
        sec_to_last = num1 % 100;
        double_sec_to_last = sec_to_last * 2;
        if (double_sec_to_last >= 10)
        {
            first_dig = double_sec_to_last / 10;
            sec_dig = double_sec_to_last % 10;
            first_sum += first_dig;
            first_sum += sec_dig;
        }
        else
        {
            first_sum += double_sec_to_last;
        }
        num1 = num1 / 100;
    }
    int num2 = num;
    while (num2 >= 10)
    {
        last = num2 % 10;
        second_sum += last;
    }
    second_sum += first_sum;
    if (second_sum % 10 == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

long check_length(long num)
{
    long num_length = floor(log10(labs(num))) + 1;
    return num_length;
}

long get_first_digits(long num)
{
    long i = num;
    while (i >= 100)
    {
        i /= 10;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Don't use a numeric type for credit card numbers, use a string. It's easier to loop over it than all that repeated division and modulus.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. That means complete (but minimal) source code that other people can compile and execute with no insertions or additions. That means showing all the lines, including lines `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include "cs50.h"`. The [mre] should also include an exact copy of input that reproduces the problem. Do not just say “some credit card numbers”; you must give a specific example. It also includes an exact copy of the wrong output (or other wrong behavior) and a sample of the behavior desired instead. Do not just say “it doesn’t even run”.

Comment: But, before that, isolate the problem.After `get_cc_number`, print the number that resulted. Is it correct? After `check_sum`, print the number that resulted. Is it correct? What is the first point at which the program went wrong? Reduce the program to the minimal amount needed to show the problem.

Comment: antoniomcoelho, `log10(labs(num))` is a problem when `num == 0` or `num == LONG_MIN` or value where conversion to `double` may round.  Consider other code to handle all possible `num`.

Comment: antoniomcoelho, when `valid == 0`, call `printf("INVALID\n");` and then exit.  Rest of code does not well handle problem values.

Answer (score 0):

A while back, I reviewed an issue like this where the user was getting tripped up on acquiring a credit card check digit.  With that, I wrote a small proof-of-principle test program that allows validation of credit card numbers using the Luhn algorithm.  Following, is that code snippet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int check_valid(char * num)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int work = 0;
    char card[20];

    if ((strlen(num) %2 == 0))  /* Even numbers - do not need a leading zero */
    {
        strcpy(card, num);
    }
    else                        /* Odd numbers - add a leading zero to evaluate */
    {
        strcpy(card, "0");
        strcat(card, num);
    }

    printf("Length of number is: %d\n", (int)strlen(num));

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(card); i++)
    {
        work = card[i] - '0';
        if ((i %2) == 0)
        {
            work = (card[i] - '0') * 2;
            if (work > 9)
            {
                work = work - 9;
            }
        }
        sum = sum + work;
        printf("Digit is: %d Value is: %d Sum is %d\n", (card[i]- '0'), work, sum);
    }

    return ((sum % 10) == 0);
}

int main()
{
    char number[20];
    int x = -1;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    x = scanf("%s", number);

    x = check_valid(number);

    if (x == 0)
        printf("Invalid\n");
    else
        printf("Valid\n");

    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't identify the card issuer, just verifies that the number is valid.

As noted in the comments, one probably would want to utilize a string entry as this code snippet does rather than trying to utilize a very large integer.  You might try going that route with a string as well.  Give this a try and see if it allows you to progress.